# C Program isn't printing strings properly

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, command-line-arguments

Here is my code at the moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WORD_LEN 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i;
    char smallest_word[WORD_LEN + 1],
         largest_word[WORD_LEN + 1],
         current_word[WORD_LEN + 1];

    current_word == argv[1];
    strcpy(smallest_word, (strcpy(largest_word, current_word)));

    for (i=2; i<argc; i++) {
        current_word == argv[i];

        if (strcmp(current_word, smallest_word) < 0) {
            strcpy(smallest_word, current_word);
        }
        else if (strcmp(current_word, largest_word) > 0) {
            strcpy(largest_word, current_word);
        }
    }

    printf("\nSmallest word: %s", smallest_word);
    printf("\nLargest word: %s", largest_word);

    return 0;
}
```

The point of this program is to take arguments (words) from the command line and compare them to see which is the smallest vs the largest (AKA alphabetical order). I feel like I have the program down and it should be working, but when I try to run the code, the output is strange squiggly characters instead. If my input was as follows, then the output would be:

Input:

```
./whatever.exe hello there general kenobi
```

Output:

```
Smallest word: ▒
Largest word: ▒
```

Whereas the correct input and output should be as follows:

Input:

```
./whatever.exe hello there general kenobi
```

Output:

```
Smallest word: general
Largest word: there
```

I am not sure if this is a type problem, or if I have something completely wrong with my program entirely. I look forward to any and all feedback

Comment: `current_word == argv[1];` does nothing - a compare of pointers that is thrown away.  I suspect you want `strcpy(current_word, argv[1]);` to copy `"hello"`.  Save time, enabled all compiler warnings.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That was it! Thank you so much!

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) "...an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and ***is not an lvalue.***"

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong way to assign a *string***

The below compares 2 pointers and then discards the result. 2 places

```
current_word == argv[1];  // Not the needed code
current_word == argv[i];
```

Instead a copy of the *string* was desired.

```
strcpy(current_word, argv[1]);
```

---

Such code is precarious as the string length of `argv[1]` may meet/exceed the size of array `current_word`.  Better code would test.  Example:

```
if (strlen(argv[1]) >= sizeof current_word)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Too big <%s>\n", argv[1]);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(current_word, argv[1]);
```